# ¿Tiene sentido «Literatura literaria»?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, terminología

En el mundo angloparlante hay una distinción entre «genre fiction» y «literary fiction». Por lo visto, [según Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literatura_de_g%C3%A9nero) el concepto de «literatura de género» existe también en el mundo hispanohablante.

Pero ¿cuál termino se usaría para traducir «literary fiction»? Porque una busqueda para «literatura literaria», aparte de sonar raro, no produce resultados.

Comment: Yo habría traducido «literary fiction» como **"ficción literaria"**. El término «Literatura literaria» suena a broma casi, como "medicina médica", "astronomía astronómica" o "música musical". No sé si hay una música musical y una música no musical, pero si lo hay debe ser algo muy específico. Quizá la pregunta se pueda beneficiar de explicar en palabras llanas qué es esa  «literary fiction» (y tb. que es la "genre fiction" y en qué se diferencian). Una vez se entiendan bien los términos y lo que definen podemos buscarles un término con la _precisa precisión_ de nuestro _metódico método_.

Comment: Sin saber porque los angloparlantes diferencian *"genre fiction"* y *"literary fiction"* es imposible dar traducciones diferentes a las literales **«género de ficción»** y **«literatura de ficción»**

Comment: No creo que la traduccion sea muy dificil. "Literary fiction" = la que a mi me gusta, "genre fiction" = la que les gusta a ellos. ;)

Answer (score 1):

En mis oídos, *literatura literaria* es un pleonasmo, a no ser que fuera un juego de palabras en algún contexto especial.